# Can a "poem" mean something else than its usual meaning? (A sentence from H.P. Lovecraft's work)

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, literature

The story is about a marble villa, which is in the following sentence referred to as a poem:

> Lone and shaken mourned the humble courts and the lower walls, for
> upon the sumptuous greater peristyle had fallen squarely the heavy
> overhanging bough of the strange new tree, reducing the stately **poem**
> in marble with odd completeness to a mound of unsightly ruins.

What does it mean? Should it perhaps imply that it was just so artistic, delicate, a piece of art (such as a poem)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be, as you suggest, a metaphor.

The marble hall (a [peristyle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peristyle)) was poetic in design, possibly referring to both its beauty and artfulness, but also its poetic rhythm of columns around the perimeter.